# with mvc.net is there an event that is raised after the view is rendered

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pipeline

I am porting an asp.net webforms application to mvc.net.  I have an OR framework that requires a DataSession object to be created before any database operations can be performed.

In my current webform application I instantiate the DataSession during the Page_Init event and during the Page_UnLoad event I clear the object.

I am looking for something similar with mvc.net.  I have initially started with using the OnACtionExecuting (raised before an action) and OnActionExecuted (raised after the action).  However, during the rendering of the page there is some lazy loading of entities that fail as the DataSession is no longer available.  What I need is something that will fire after the View has been rendered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't let lazy loading occur in your view pages.  That means the view accesses data which breaks the entire point of MVC.

Instead you should get the entirety of the data in your controller and then pass that to your view.

Comment: jfar- agreed 100%. caching, lazy loading has soo much more to be gained from at a level where it can be leveraged by 'n'. +1

Answer (score 2):

Load the db connection in `OnActionExecuting`  and unload in `OnResultExecuted`.

Although I would use `Application_BeginRequest` and `Application_EndRequest` in global.asax.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used these methods before, but perhaps look into overriding OnResultExecuted or OnResultExecuting.